# Restore msdb database in new instance using script?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I generated the script for the `msdb` database of our `SQL Server 2008` installation since it has several `sql server jobs` and `mail` configurations. I will restore in a `sql server 2016` instance.

What would I need to do before I run the script? It says I shouldn't drop `msdb`, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Should I also restore `model` database? Are there any other database that I need to restore?

Comment: YOu can't restore a 2008 msdb database on SQL Server 2016; doing so would be a **very** bad idea if it does let you. You only (if you must) restore a system database with a copy that is from another SQL Server which has an **identical** version number. 2008 and 2016 are vastly different.

Comment: *(On a note to your question you deleted earlier, as you didn't give me time to respond, I just want to say that SSISDB is a huge improvement on the old deployment methods; I strongly recommend you learn it and use it. Just simple things like project parameters is a massive deal.)*

Answer (score 0):

I would normally approach this by scripting and transferring the objects rather than restoring MSDB to a different instance.

Check out the Powershell based [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/commands/) and specifically the Migration cmdlets. These will let you transfer all of the objects directly.